# Why $\left|\frac{1}{x^{z}}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|^{\Re(z)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $x\in \mathbb R$ and $z\in \mathbb C$.
Why $$\left|\frac{1}{x^{z}}\right|=\frac{1}{|x|^{\Re(z)}}\ \ ?$$

I tried as follow $$\left|\frac{1}{x^z}\right|=\frac{1}{|x|^{\Re(z)}|x|^{i\Im(z)}}.$$
Then $$|x|^{i\Im(z)}=e^{i\Im(z)\ln(|x|)},$$
but why would it be $1$ ?

Comment: Sorry but what is a curriculum where they teach you that manipulating entities such as $$x^z$$ with $x$ real and $z$ complex not real, is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Because, if $t\in\mathbb R$, then

1. $e^{it} = \cos(t)+i\sin t$
2. $\sin^2t + \cos^2t=1$

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to see that. By example observe that if $w=e^{ix}$ for $x\in\Bbb R$ then $\bar w=e^{-ix}$. Hence

$$|w|=|e^{ix}|=\sqrt{w\bar w}=\sqrt{e^{ix}e^{-ix}}=\sqrt1=1$$

Other way: if we write the complex number $z$ in polar form we have that $z=|z|e^{i\arg(z)}$, this imply that

$$|z|=|z||e^{i\arg(z)}|\implies 1=|e^{i\arg(z)}|$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\left|\frac{1}{x^z}\right| = \frac{1}{\left|x^{\Re z+\mathrm i\Im z}\right|}
=\frac{1}{\left|x^{\Re z} x^{\mathrm i\Im z}\right|}=\frac{1}{\left|x^{\Re z}\right|}\frac{1}{\left| x^{\mathrm \Im z}\right|}=\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|^{\Re z}\frac{1}{\left|x^{\mathrm i\Im z}\right|}$$
So what remains to show is that $\left|x^{\mathrm i\Im z}\right|=1$. For this we write
$$\left|x^{\mathrm i\Im z}\right| = \left|\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(\Im z)\ln x}\right|$$
Since $x\in\mathbb R$, so is $\ln x$, and $\Im z$ is real by definition. But $\left|\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}\right|=1$ for $\phi\in\mathbb R$.